# параллельные тесты в Jenkins -> один аллюр отчет по прогонам

Tags: jenkins, allure, jenkins-pipeline

поставил перед собой задачу либо а) сгенерировать два отчета по обоим прогонам либо б) объединить результаты обоих прогонов в один отчет. вот мой скрипт пайплайн:

```
pipeline {
    agent none
    tools {
        maven 'Maven 3.8.6' 
    }
    stages {
        stage('Run tests'){
            parallel {
                stage('Test on DEV') {
                    agent {
                        label 'node_02_jdk_17'
                    }
                    steps {
                        cleanWs()
                        git branch: 'develop', credentialsId: 'git', url: 'https://Jenking_GIT@automated-tests.git'
                        withEnv(["ALLURE_RESULTS=target/allure-results-dev"]) {
                            sh "mvn test -P UI -Dallure.results.directory=${env.ALLURE_RESULTS} -Dtarget.env=dev -Dtest=LogIn"
                        }
                    }
                    post {
                        always {
                            allure([
                                includeProperties: true,
                                jdk: '',
                                properties: [[key: 'allure.results.directory', value: 'target/allure-results-dev']],
                                reportBuildPolicy: 'ALWAYS',
                                results: [[path: 'target/allure-results-dev']]
                            ])
                        }
                    }
                }
                stage('Test on QA') {
                    agent {
                        label 'node_02_jdk_17'
                    }
                    steps {
                        git branch: 'develop', credentialsId: 'git', url: 'https://Jenking_GIT@automated-tests.git'
                        withEnv(["ALLURE_RESULTS=target/allure-results-qa"]) {
                            sh "mvn test -P UI -Dallure.results.directory=${env.ALLURE_RESULTS} -Dtarget.env=qa -Dtest=UserPreferences"
                        }
                    }
                    post {
                        always {
                            allure([
                                includeProperties: true,
                                jdk: '',
                                properties: [[key: 'allure.results.directory', value: 'target/allure-results-qa']],
                                reportBuildPolicy: 'ALWAYS',
                                results: [[path: 'target/allure-results-qa']]
                            ])
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

но в данном случае получается так, что генерится два отчета, но они одинаковые и именно теста 'LogIn'. хотя тесты бегут успешно, все ок. но вот с отчетами беда. помогите пожалуйста? или хотябы скажите точно, что такого с моим подходом никак не добиться и посоветуйте/дайте решение, как все-таки добиться результата?